# Default Locale Used by MSI

Tags: windows-installer, default, locale

Which flavor of Spanish locale is supported by default when building MSI installers?
ES_MX?
ES_AR?
ES_LE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An MSI package uses the language you set, usually English. Some tools can also create multilingual installers which support multiple languages.

So MSI packages don't support Spanish by default unless you specifically configure them to use Spanish.

Comment: thanks for the reply! when i do configure an MSI to support spanish, wht is the default locale that is used?

Comment: It will use the locale you set for it. Each locale has a different ID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx . When you create a MSI, you can set that ID in the MSI summary information. Perhaps you are asking the wrong question. What do you need to do?

Comment: I guess what I mean is which Spanish locale Microsoft supports in their official 34 built-in languages for MSI?

Comment: Where did you read that? MSI packages support all languages listed in the article I mentioned and there a lot more than 34. So the answer would be MSI supports all Spanish locales.

Comment: MSI has a built in list of 35 languages including English, I was referring to the locale of the Spanish language in that list..